# Create a batch to read the label of a drive and create a txt

Tags: batch-file, label

I need to create a Batch that will create a .txt file that is named after the label of a disc and contains the files and directories of that disk.
For e.g. I have a usb drive in (drive F: and label 'blabla'),
I need to ask the user which drive it is (user will need to enter the drive letter) and then the batch file will create a .txt file named blabla.txt which will contain the files and directories of that drive.
Any ideas?

---

OK, here is where I am:

```
echo off & setlocal enableextensions    
CLS  
echo[    
set /p drive=What is the Drive Letter:    
set /p ampm=type AM or PM:    
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol %drive%') do (
   set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
DIR %drive% /S gen > C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~8,4%%ampm%_%vol%.txt
```

It works like a charm but the problem is it does not add the .txt extension to the file it creates. Any idea on that?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Having said that, I will also point you to SS64's pages on the [`VOL` command](https://ss64.com/nt/vol.html), [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), and the [`DIR` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html); I will also note that you're probably better off trying to use the volume serial number rather than the volume name, as many devices either don't have a volume name, or have duplicate volume names (if they're from the same manufacturer, for example).

Comment: @SteveFest - I'll mention that I wrote a disk cataloger in batch many many years ago; this is not something that *I* would waste my time writing for someone else, or asking someone to write for me - it's just too easy with minimal research. That's why I wrote the comment I did, to point out just how easy it is to get the necessary information on one's own.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You are correct indeed. My answer is only partial. And the important parts are "code-missing". Even with all my information in the answer, the OP will still be unable to make a working code unless he/she does research using `command /?`, or as you suggested - SS64.com/nt

Comment: @SteveFest - I absolutely _love_ SS64 as a batch reference. You'll find that I link to it in most if not all of my comments and answers relating to batch...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Me too. I've set shortcut to SS64 and, almost every time I write batch/vbs/powershell, I will have a SS64 fired up.

Comment: Hi all, you are correct and I am sorry if I violated any of the rules here. I am not a coder, I just managed to gather info from the web about this and tried to give it a shot. I have made so many changes to the batch file that I got lost. I will try to restore it to the point it was and post it here.

Comment: I added the code I have so far below. What commands should I use to 'take' the label and apply it to the filename? With my limited knowledge, I think I have to 'take' the label and apply it to a name (like the set /p)  and then stick it to the end of the filename as %something% for example, am I close?

Answer (score 2):

## `FOR` Metavariable

I do not recommend using pure numeric variable name as it may conflict with command-line argument, `%1` - `%9`.

## Drive Letter

---

```
dir %drive%
```

should be changed to

```
dir %drive%:
```

`dir` requires a `:` to understand that is a drive, not a folder or a file.

---

## No `.txt` Extension

I could not understand the problem since I cannot reproduce such situation on my machine. However, you can wrap the path with quotes. It is a Windows-wide precaution.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~8,4%%ampm%_%vol%.txt
```

becomes

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~8,4%%ampm%_%vol%.txt"
```

Comment: Love the _And the code is intended to be messy and confusing_ part.

Comment: OK, here is where I am:

echo off & setlocal enableextensions
CLS
echo[

set /p drive=What is the Drive Letter:
set /p ampm=type AM or PM:
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol %drive%') do (
   set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
DIR %drive% /S gen > C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~8,4%%ampm%_%vol%.txt


It works like a charm but the problem is it does not add the .txt extension to the file it creates. Any idea on that?

Comment: I only see you put CLS and ECHO together.

Comment: @TGrif To be honest, I don't like people copy and pasting my code without any effort. But since OP has provided code, I can do that no more. But when I answer such questions, I always leave some bits hidden.

Comment: @SteveFest I'm not a _batch-file_ guy, but I'm sure you're right. Don't take it personally however. You already gived some good advices here. But, wait... You change your answer didn't you ?

Comment: @TGrif Yes, I changed my answer as OP showed his/her code. This way my previous answer won't make any sense and outdated. That's why I've changed my answer to specifically fix his/her issue in the code.